# Add class to the body of my WordPress website, if user visits it trough my Android Webview App

Tags: android, html, wordpress, android-webview

I want to give my WordPress-site some extra styling and maybe also some modified functionality, if it is visited through my Android WebView application, so i need to find a way, to distinguish it from other WebView Apps.

I am planing, to mark visits through the app by adding a css-class to the sites body.

Which ways are there, to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {
  // Do something!
  // Redirect to Android-site?
   document.getElementById("yourelement").classList.add('yourclass');
}
```

try this...

Comment: it should just happen through my app, not every WebView app.

Comment: you can use state management for this to know whether request sent by your app or other.Then the issue is not the same as you specify above.

Comment: how would you specify it, to make clear, what i want to achieve?

Comment: it's not like this you can rethink your comment once and redeemed to my suggestion it's not more then a suggestion if you think it relates than it's good.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to add a class is using js.

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1)
    $('html').addClass('is-android');
```

if you want to add the class with php, you should use a hook like
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/body_class

but it could be that:

1) your theme does not use the WP `body_class()` function

2) or the user agent header is not set int the `$_SERVER` var

Comment: where does it specify, to add the class just, if the visitor comes from my app and not from every webview app?

Comment: sry, I do not understand your question/problem